# Trying to replace a value from a column by it's parent in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

[[image: query result]

I want to be able to show the EquipementName, where fk_EquipementParentId = pk_EquipementId.

How would I build my query?

This is what I have so far...

select pk_EquipementId
,fk_EquipementParentId

--, query AS 'Parent Name'

,EquipementName
,EquipementInstallationDate
from Firm.dbo.Equipement
where fk_EquipementTypeId in (3,15) and bEquipementTemplate = 0

Answer (score 1):

you can do a self-join

```
select t1.*, t2.EquipementName as parentName
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.fk_EquipementParentId = t2.pk_EquipementId
```